# Collapse optgroups by default in Jquery uix multiselect plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use the jquery uix multiselect plugin found here:

https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect

It works fine, except I need to have my optgroups collapsed by default. How can this be done?

Comment: show your code for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is the documectation [link](https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect/wiki/API-Documentation)
collapsableGroups (boolean) (default: true) : tells whether the option groups can be collapsed or not

```
// initialize option
$(selector).multiselect({ collapsableGroups: false });
```

or this [one](https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect/issues/49)

```
var sel = $("#yourSelect").multiselect();
setTimeout(function() {  // let the refresh method happen
    $("#multiselect_groups").next().find("div.group-element").parent()
    .each(function() { 
        if ($(this).data("fnToggle")) $(this).data("fnToggle")(); 
    });
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. However, I need the optgroups to be collapsed by default. The collapsableGroups only gives me the ability to collapse them.

Comment: this discribed in issues https://github.com/yanickrochon/jquery.uix.multiselect/issues/49 so there is no solution is current version